# Conjecture on a stronger form of Chinese Remainder Theorem (on ideals): $\prod_{i=1}^m A_i+\prod_{i=m+1}^n A_i\overset{?}{=}R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, chinese-remainder-theorem

Notation: By two ideals $A,B$ in $R$ are comaximal we mean $A+B=R$.

Assume $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$, and
$\{A_i\}_{1\le i\le n}$ are pairwise-comaximal ideals in $R$.
The Chinese Remainder Theorem states $A_1$ is coprime with $\prod\limits_{2\le i\le n} A_i$.
I wonder if for all $m\in \{1,\cdots, n-1\}$,
$\prod\limits_{1\le i\le m} A_i$ and $\prod\limits_{m+1\le i\le n} A_i$ are comaximal?

The proof for the Chinese Remainder Theorem seems failing to be rewritten to handle such case. So I believe some counterexample exists, but I can not find any.

Comment: This is a trivial question: if a maximal ideal contains the two products, then it contains two of the given ideals.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks, this proof is also elegant! If $\prod_{i=1}^m A_i+\prod_{i=m+1}^n A_i\ne R$, then it is contained in a maximal ideal $ M$. If for each $1\le i\le m$, $A_i$ is not contained in $ M$, then for each $1\le i\le m$, select $x_i\in A_i$ s.t. $x_i\notin M$. Then $x_1\cdots x_m\in \prod_{i=1}^m A_i$. On the other hand $ M$ is maximal, and hence prime, and then $x_i\notin M$ implies $x_1\cdots x_m\notin M$, a contradiction. That is $ M$ contains one of $A_1,\cdots, A_m$, and also contains one of $A_{m+1},\cdots,A_n$ by a same argument, contradicting $A_i+A_j=R$ if $i\ne j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following lemma :
We can Prove that if I is an ideal that is comaximal with the ideals $A_{j}$ for all $j \in \{1,....n\}$ then I and $\prod_{j} A_j$ are comaximal. 
Now back to your question. Let $m \in \{1,....,n\}$. 
For all $j \in \{1,...,m\}$ : $A_j$ is comaximal with $\prod_{m+1\le i\le n} A_i$.
I think you can apply the lemma above with $I=\prod_{m+1\le i\le n} A_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be pairwise coprime, i.e. $A_i+A_j = (1)$ if $i \neq j$. Then the two product ideals $\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i$ and $\prod_{i=m+1}^{n} A_i$ are coprime for all $m =1,\dots,n$.

Let $x_{(i,j)}+y_{(i,j)}=1$ with $i \neq j$, $x_{(i,j)} \in A_i$ and $y_{(i,j)} \in A_j$. This is possible since $A_i$ and $A_j$ are coprime. Now consider the product
$$
1= \prod_{i=1,\dots,m}\prod_{j=m+1,\dots,n} (x_{(i,j)}+y_{(i,j)}).
$$
Each summand is in $\prod_{i=1}^{m} A_i$ or in $\prod_{i=m+1}^{n} A_i$.